# PHP Regex for commenting with {# and #}, but ignore it if {{# and #}}

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to create comment using PHP regex, something like

```
This is a great day.

{# This is a secret message. #}

Have a great Christmas!
```

If processed with preg_replace() it should become

```
This is a great day.

Have a great Christmas!
```

But adding additional curly brackets, it will be ignored, so the following

```
This is a great day.

{{# This is a secret message. #}}

Have a great Christmas!
```

will display as

```
This is a great day.

{# This is a secret message. #}

Have a great Christmas!
```

How can I pull this off? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex to identify the "comments" to be removed:

```
(?<!\{)(\{#.*?#\})(?!\})
```

Following this, you could use the regex below to identify your messages; use the second named sub-group to extract them:

```
(?<=\{)(\{#.*?#\})(?=\})
```